# Can lsof display the real path instead the bind mount path of a docker container?

Tags: container, lsof, bind-mount

I try to find out which files are in use in a specific path:

```
lsof /mnt/cache
```

This returns for example:

```
COMMAND     PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE  SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME
Plex\x20S   338 nobody  cwd    DIR  259,1        74 3221225602 /config/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/Plug-in Support/Data/com.plexapp.system
```

As you can see "NAME" does not contain the path "/mnt/cache". And there isn't any "/config" dir available on the host system:

```
ls /config
/bin/ls: cannot access '/config': No such file or directory
```

This is because /config is a Docker bind mount to /mnt/cache/appdata/plex, which exists only inside a specific container:

```
docker inspect plex
...
        "Mounts": [
...
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/mnt/cache/appdata/plex",
                "Destination": "/config",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
```

Can `lsof` display the real source path, so it looks like this?

```
Plex\x20S   338 nobody  cwd    DIR  259,1        74 3221225602 /mnt/cache/appdata/plex/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/Plug-in Support/Data/com.plexapp.system
```